# Python: Compare List with a List in File

Tags: python, file, list

I am strugling with this problem that looks simple but I'm stuck! Well, I have to build a function where I receive a list of categories like:

```
input Example1: ['point_of_interest', 'natural_feature', 'park', 'establishment']
input Example2: ['point_of_interest', 'establishment']
input Example3: ['sublocality', 'political']
```

So that list could be with variable elements inside I guess from 1 till 4 not more

So with this same data I am gonna create a file with that input in a way that **if the new input is not in the file, append it to the file**.

The way is each list is an element itself, I mean I have to compare the full elements of the list and if I can find other list exactly equal I don´t have to add it.

In my code I just tried to add the first element in the file because really I don't know how to add the full list to compare with the next list.

```
def categories(category):
    number = 0
    repeat = False
    if os.path.exists("routes/svm/categories"):
        with open('routes/svm/categories', 'rb') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for categoryFile in spamreader:
                if (cmp(categoryFile,category) == 0):
                    number += 1
                    repeat = True
                if not repeat:
                    categoriesFile = open('routes/svm/categories', 'a') 
                    category = str(category[0])     
                    categoriesFile.write(category) 
                    categoriesFile.write('\n')
                    categoriesFile.close()
                else:
                    categoriesFile = open('routes/svm/categories', 'w')
                    category = str(category[0])     
                    categoriesFile.write(category)
                    categoriesFile.write('\n')
                    categoriesFile.close()
```

EDIT: Some explanation by  @KlausWarzecha: Users might enter a list with (about 4) items. If this list ( = this combination of items) is not in the file already, you want to add the list (and not the items separately!) to the file? –

Comment: Why can't you just write all elements one by one to the file? Your question is hard to understand for me

Comment: @MichaelButscher i received a list in my functions, i have to compare with the list that i have in file, is this new list is not in the file i have to add it, basically that is the problem. sorry for my english

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand.

Comment: are you trying to get a list of unique elements and writing them to a file?

Comment: @taonico Ok, why can't you write all list elements (and not only the first) in a for-loop to the file?

Comment: @taonico Do we get this right: Users might enter a list with (about 4) items. If this list ( = this combination of items) is not in the file already, you want to add the list (and not the items separately!) to the file?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha exactly!

Comment: @taonico Great, we're getting closer :) There's one more thing to consider: I do assume that the order of items in a user request is irrelevant and it is just the combination of terms that counts. So, before we compare the list of items which the user has just entered with the "list of lists" of all previous requests, we have to sort the user input to avoid duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really simple. You may take the following approach if it works for you:

1. Read all the contents of the CSV into a list
2. Add all the non-matching items from the input into this list
3. re-write the CSV file

You may start with this sample code:

```
# input_list here represents the inputs
# You may get input from some other source too
input_list = [['point_of_interest', 'natural_feature', 'park', 'establishment'], ['point_of_interest', 'establishment'], ['sublocality', 'political']]
category_list = []
with open('routes/svm/categories', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for categoryFile in spamreader:
        print categoryFile
        category_list.append(categoryFile)
for item in input_list:
    if (item in category_list):
        print "Found"
    else:
        category_list.append(item)
        print "Not Found"

# Write `category_list` to the CSV file
```

> Please use this code as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: @theghosfc its like just the input list is just a list instead of list of list

Comment: @taonico, the input is just a list. So, the example mentioned above show 3 different inputs at 3 different runs of the program? Also, how is the data stored in the CSV File. Only one column or multiple? Could you share 2-3 sample records from the CSV file for better understanding?